# How to store integers from a list within a list?

Tags: python, list, integer

```
children = [1220, 1221, 2220, 2221, 2222, 3220, 3221, 4220, 4221, 5220]
child_list = []
child_inc = 1

for i in children:
    digits = [str(x) for x in str(i)]
    if int(digits[0]) == child_inc:
        var = str("".join(digits))
        child_list.append([var])
        child_inc += 1
print(child_list)
```

I'm trying to break down `children` into a list of lists, first convert them to a string, and read the first digit. if the first digit is a 1, then append to a list, and store that in `child_list[0]`. Then, for the integers beginning with 2, sort them into another list at `child_list[1]` and so on.

Right now this code can only find the first item which matches the criteria. It doesn't matter that the final output is a string.
Thanks.

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: What is this supposed to do `digits = [str(x) for x in str(i)]`? It does exactly the same as `list(str(i))`. The first `str` call is completely redundant.

Comment: Do you want to cope with all possible digits `0` to `9` and give empty lists for those with no matches?

Comment: "put the numbers that start with a 1 in `child_list[0]` then the numbers that start with a 2 in `child_list[1]` ...." you know if you used a dictionary you could just do `child_dict[string_number[0]].append(string_number)` or similar (probably with `defaultdict(list)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an auxiliary list, and do a nested loop, doing this would be:

```
children = [1220, 1221, 2220, 2221, 2222, 3220, 3221, 4220, 4221, 5220]
child_list = []

for i in range(1,6):
    lst = []
    for num in children:
      digits = str(num)
      if int(digits[0]) == i:
            lst.append(digits)
    child_list.append(lst)

print(child_list)

res => [['1220', '1221'], ['2220', '2221', '2222'], ['3220', '3221'], ['4220', '4221'], ['5220']]
```

Comment: You're not using `child_inc` are you?

Comment: @doctorlove You are right, thanks!

Comment: Nice answer Benjamin

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the next code segment:

`elif int(digits[0]) == 2:
     var = str("".join(digits))
     child_list2.append([var])`

And remove the line:
`child_inc += 1`

This line prevents from all other items that match the criteria to be found.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the `str` at the top where you get the digits.
You seem to want to build up a list per starting digits.
Run the `child_inc` over the digits you need and check what you have.
You were incrementing this inside your if, so would only get the first item that matched.
Something like this:

```
children = [1220, 1221, 2220, 2221, 2222, 3220, 3221, 4220, 4221, 5220]
child_list = []

for child_inc in range(1,10):
    kids = [] #<--- new list for this digit
    for i in children:
        digits = str(i)
        if int(digits[0]) == child_inc:
            var = str("".join(digits))
            kids.append(var)
    child_list.append(kids)
print(child_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a dict approach is better here :

```
children = [1220, 1221, 2220, 2221, 2222, 3220, 3221, 4220, 4221, 5220]

strs = [ str(x) for x in children]
res=defaultdict(list)
for s in strs :
    res[s[0]].append(s[1:])

print(list(res.values()))

#[['220', '221'], ['220', '221', '222'], ['220', '221'], ['220', '221'], ['220']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's first understand the actual problem :

> Example hint :

So suppose you have a list :

```
a=[(2006,1),(2007,4),(2008,9),(2006,5)]
```

And you want to convert this to a dict as the first element of the tuple as key and second element of the tuple. something like :

```
{2008: [9], 2006: [5], 2007: [4]}
```

But there is a catch you also want that those keys which have different values but keys are same  like (2006,1) and (2006,5) keys are same but values are different. you want that those values append with only one key so expected output :

```
{2008: [9], 2006: [1, 5], 2007: [4]}
```

for this type of problem we do something like this:

first create a new dict then we follow this pattern:

```
if item[0] not in new_dict:
    new_dict[item[0]]=[item[1]]
else:
    new_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])
```

So we first check if key is in new dict and if it already then add the value of duplicate key to its value:

full code:

```
a=[(2006,1),(2007,4),(2008,9),(2006,5)]

new_dict={}

for item in a:
    if item[0] not in new_dict:
        new_dict[item[0]]=[item[1]]
    else:
        new_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])

print(new_dict)
```

Now back to actual problem :

You can use this pattern and save the int with same first number :

```
children = [1220, 1221, 2220, 2221, 2222, 3220, 3221, 4220, 4221, 5220]
track={}
for i in children:
    if str(i)[:1] not in track:
        track[str(i)[:1]]=[i]
    else:
        track[str(i)[:1]].append(i)

print(track.values())
```

output:

```
[[3220, 3221], [4220, 4221], [1220, 1221], [2220, 2221, 2222], [5220]]
```